# Access Violation on char array

Tags: c++, access-violation, strcmp, arrays

I'm getting an access violation on a char array I *just* created using `new`.

```
DispatchCommand(char* cmdStr)
        {
            // Dispatch
            for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(_lpCommands); i++)
            {
                const int len = strlen(_lpCommands[i].szCommand);
                char* cmdblip = new char[len + 1];
                memcpy(&cmdblip, cmdStr, len);
                cmdblip[len] = '\0';  // Access Violation

                if(strcmp(cmdblip, _lpCommands[i].szCommand) == 0)
                {
                    if(strlen(cmdStr) > strlen(_lpCommands[i].szCommand))
                        (*_lpCommands[i].cbCallback)(&cmdStr[strlen(_lpCommands[i].szCommand)]);
                    else
                        (*_lpCommands[i].cbCallback)("");

                    delete cmdblip;
                    return;
                }

                delete cmdblip;
            }

            // Error and return
            *Out::ServerInfo<<"Command not found!"<<ENDL;
        }
```

_lpCommands is an array of `Command` structures:

```
struct Command
{
    char* szCommand;
    CommandCallback cbCallback;
};
```

The produced error message is:

> Unhandled exception at 0x012219cf in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation writing location 0x66647366.

This was a rewrite of similar code which was using `memcmp`, which ended up giving me an access violation as well without be doing a `memcpy`.

What gives?

Comment: Why not `std::string`? And you have undefined behavior in `delete cmdblip;`. It should be `delete [] cmdblip;`.

Comment: @FredLarson - Trying to strafe away from std::string for this particular part of the program. And thank you for the tip!

Comment: Don't try to stay away from `std::string`, try to stay away from `char*`!

Comment: Not using `std::string` is too localized. This code is the fuglies, and the fact that it errors is a direct consequence of the fact that your code sucks terribly, rather than any specific instance of suck.

Comment: As the marked answer stated, I had a typo and was passing a pointer to a pointer. My code works perfectly after changing that. I needed to stay away from std::string for *that particular section of code*. Cool your jets, kiddos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't pass `&cmdblip` to `memcpy`. You should pass a pointer to the destination buffer, not a pointer to that pointer. Pass `cmdblip` instead.

Edit: I agree that in general, std::string should be used in C++. Still, the technical reason this code crashes is that `memcpy` corrupts the `cmdblip` pointer, making it point on a memory location that is actually made of the first 4 bytes of the copied string. Then, `cmdblip[len]` results in a memory location that is not within the allocated buffer (or any other legally allocated buffer), hence the crash. So, if you want to write better code, use C++ classes. And if you want to understand why the given code crashed, consider the above.

Comment: Ah, silly typo. It's been a long night. That seemed to work! Thank you!

Comment: @Di-0xide You still need to change `delete` to `delete[]`, even if it apears to work.

Comment: Yeah, and while at it, change the type of the `cmdStr` argument to a `const char*`. You're not modifying that string in your code, so protect yourself from accidental modifications in the future.

Comment: @eran: Yeah. The only possible answer to this question is "use `std::string`". You may as well be solving the problems of the unemployed by giving them a bed for one night- it's not really a solution *at all*.

Comment: @DeadMG, please place your mouse on that little down pointing arrow you've clicked. It should pop a message saying: "This answer is not useful". My answer is definitively useful - it solved the issue in question. If you want to be a purist, you can state your mind on your own answer, as you've done. Don't abuse downvoting - this answer is perfectly correct, even if it doesn't change the OP's general approach toward C++ programming.

Comment: @eran: Your answer is *not* useful. All you've done is delayed the OP's problem by the length of time that it takes him to have to maintain that function or write a new one. You haven't solved anything. The real problem here is that the OP's code sucks, and this is but one of the *many* errors he *will* encounter, frequently, until it is rectified. The specific error in the question is merely a symptom, and rectifying it solves nothing.

Comment: @DeadMG - "The only possible answer to this question is "use std::string"" - hardly? My code works fine. Eran's answer was the answer to my question. As I have stated more than twice now is that *I needed to get away from `std::string` for this particular section of code*.

Answer (score 5):

The only possible helpful answer to this question is "Use `std::string`". The specific problem you are having now will simply re-occur, or an identical one, every time you modify this function or write another like it. The only way to solve the problem in the general case is to move to a class-based solution, which is kindly provided for you as Standard. For example, your current code is exception unsafe, on top of whatever is giving you an access violation, not to mention that it's unreadable and begging for a number of other errors, such as off-by-one, not properly NULL terminating, double deletes, and memory leaks. Oh, and UB because you `delete` what you `new[]`.

Comment: @DomagojPandža - `char*` are 'actual C++'. I even stated I wanted to strafe away from strings in *this particular section of code*. I didn't say I wasn't using string anywhere else.

Comment: That leaves a question: _why_?

Comment: @Di-0xide: `char*` are most definitely not C++.

Comment: Since when are `char`'s and `pointers` not C++? *C Strings* may not be 'C++' but last time I checked you couldn't have C++ without a `char` scalar type.

Comment: You say you used std::strings everywhere else, just not here. And you managed to get an access violation in this particular part, gee, I can only guess how that happened. That's why we object such approaches. You need to own the knowledge and experience to deal with such situations, but when you already have it - you'll opt in to develop safer solutions or use the standard library. That mess you wrote upstairs is signature C. C++ was brought forth for a lot more than just classes.

Comment: @DomagojPandža - That's great, but I'm not here to gain approval of the choice to use char arrays as opposed to `std::string`. I was instructed that we needed to keep this part of the code non-`std::string` for a damn good reason. It isn't difficult to just answer the question and make a kind suggestion instead of seeming to know that I am personally a terrible programmer.